# How to make position:absolute divs follow the paddings of a position:relative parent;

Tags: html, css

Having `box-sizing:border-box;` enabled, how can I make a `position:absolute;` div with 100% width and height follow the sizing of a parent div with paddings?

edit - http://jsfiddle.net/cLzhffa7/

Is it possible for #first to be just like #second while having position:absolute;

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve. A visual would be helpful.

Comment: My understanding you are expecting absolute top position inside of padding content. As per [CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) top position should be  always top of the div. [check it out JSfiddle url](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/kv1qfcvw/)

Comment: Its not possible to make absolute top position below the padding. but you can use margin or border instead of padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the margin of your child to the same as the padding of your parent, then set `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` to `0` instead of defining a width and height:

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  background:#000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:20px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLzhffa7/4/)

Comment: Looks like this might be it. I was thinking about putting a container between the parent and the child, but your solution seems to be better. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ekkdwchw/)**

from your description in question

html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    border:2px solid;
}
.child{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:2px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

---

If you don't want to use margin

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ekkdwchw/1/)**

css

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    border:2px solid;
    width:200px;
}
.child{
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
}
```

Comment: I want the parent's padding work though. In your demo's case, I want to have a 10px gap between the parent's and the child's borders...

Comment: Yep, that works too, but I'll use the answer above instead. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can make them the same if you just delete this css code

```
#first {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just make the position relative?